# sql function input

Tags: mysql, sql

Create a function that accepts an item Id as input and returns the retail price of that item. Name the function itemPrice.

I guess my only question is how exactly to accept something as an input in MySQL. I've researched thoroughly, believe me. All I've found are things related to Oracle which is not what I'm using.

Comment: Hint:  `CREATE FUNCTION`.

Comment: I doubt you've researched thoroughly. Everything is and starts here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20))
mysql> RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
    -> RETURN CONCAT('Hello, ',s,'!');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT hello('world');
+----------------+
| hello('world') |
+----------------+
| Hello, world!  |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html